# Angular FormGroup - valuesChanges not receiving next value

Tags: angular

I'm getting lost trying to understand how to deal with `FormGroup`(s).

Basically, I built a `FormGroup`:

```
this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
   action: this.formBuilder.group({
      name: '',
      properties: this.formBuilder.array(...)
   })
})
```

Each element of the `properties` `FormArray` is created using:

```
this.formBuilder.group({
    key: ['...', Validators.required],
    value: ['...', Validators.required]
})
```

---

Than, the inner `FormGroup` `action` is passed as `Input` to a `Component`:

```
<my-component>
   [formGroup]="formGroup.controls.action"
</my-component>
```

Inside `MyComponent` I transform the `action.properties` `FormArray` in a list of `FormControl`, re-using the already created controls.

```
const defaultFormProperties = {}

const formProperties = this.formGroup.controls.properties as FormArray
formProperties.controls.forEach(control => { 
   defaultFormProperties[control.value.key] = control.controls.value // I'm reusing the FormControl
})

this.defaultPropertiesGroup = this.formBuilder.group(defaultFormProperties)
```

However when a value of those re-used `FormControl`(s) changes, the initial `FormGroup` isn't notified. Is this an expected behavior?

I'm assuming the `FormControl`(s) get the parent changed when being included in a new `FormGroup`, right?

**EDIT**: I was assuming right. Doing a

```
Object.values(this.defaultPropertiesGroup.controls)
      .forEach(control => control.setParent(this.formGroup))
```

fixes the `valuesChanges` notification.

Comment: what is your requirement? why are projecting the formvalue?

Comment: @Chellappan I need to "flatten" the `FormArray` to build a dynamic form. Similar to https://toddmotto.com/angular-dynamic-components-forms

Comment: You are not following this tutorial?

Comment: @Chellappan I am, almost, but the original data comes from a FormArray. And I want everything to stay in sync automatically

Comment: Can you create stackblitz